# System.console null in a gradle java task

Tags: gradle

I am invoking my main class like this from a gradle file and when I am trying to read the password using System.console I am getting a NPE .

```
task (getRepositoryInfo, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
standardInput = System.in
standardOutput = System.out
environment('TERM', 'dumb')
main = 'com.devpt.explorer.Demo'
mainClassName = 'com.devpt.explorer.Demo'
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
def stageName = project.hasProperty("STAGE_NAME")? project.getProperty("STAGE_NAME"): "stageXXXX"
def operations = project.hasProperty("OPERATIONS")? project.getProperty("OPERATIONS"): "ALL"
def buildId = project.hasProperty("BUILD_ID")? project.getProperty("BUILD_ID"): "DUMMY"
args operations
args stageName
args buildId
}
```

System.console is coming as null in java main class. But I am able to read the password directly from the gradle file.
What am I doing wrong ?

code sample: https://github.com/ajayboseac/GradleExample

gradle version 2.2
java version : 1.7.0_13

Comment: Could you please provide a runnable example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: added the link to git hub

Comment: How do you run your build? Shell command or IDE? I [used to work with System.console() from a task inside a plugin](https://github.com/madhead/gradle-backup-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/by/dev/madhead/gbp/tasks/gdrive/ObtainGoogleDriveTokensTask.java#L51) (or from build src dir), and it works ok.

Comment: I am running it from the bash.

Answer (score 1):

I had posted the question in gradle and got a confirmation that console is expected to be null

link:  https://discuss.gradle.org/t/system-console-null-in-a-gradle-java-task/9274

quoting from the answer:

> The forked process isn't attached to a console. This is only possible
>   to achieve by using the JDK process builder API with Java 7. Here's an
>   article I found on the topic after a quick search:
>   http://tamanmohamed.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/jdk7-processbuilder-and-how-redirecting.html2
>
> Gradle doesn't yet support inherit streams for forked processes via
>   its JavaExec and Exec tasks.